# Stamping feet to get my attention?

Tags: communication

I've noticed a pattern about people who work in my office building: when they want to come into my office and talk with me, they'll first "stamp" both feet when they arrive at my door frame (I usually leave my door open). It's obviously louder than their normal walking steps, so I assume it's deliberate as a way to get my attention to notice their presence. I noticed it happens quite a bit and a lot of different people do it.

Anyone else experience/do this? Is this some kind of natural behavior that humans are compelled to do, or maybe a learned behavior from working in my particular company? It doesn't bother me, I just find it curious.

For the record, I'm 100% sure that I just give a few gentle knocks on the door when I enter someone's office.

Comment: It may be cultural, I have only experienced this behavior with a specific culture.

Comment: _"Anyone else experience/do this?"_ Yes, 20 yrs ago during my military service everytime a subordinate entered my office ;)

Comment: Have you ever been startled out of your wits by someone approaching quietly until you suddenly look up and notice them there? Has this happened more than once? Is it generally known that you are easily startled?

Comment: @sf02 Which culture is that?

Comment: Do you face toward or away from the door? (Could it be done to avoid ‘sneaking up on you’?)

Comment: To add to this - I feel a region/culture tag is needed here before we can attempt to answer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use your words to suggest they knock on the door instead?

Comment: If there is no door to knock upon, then a simple clearing of the throat is common practice.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that came to mind is that they are stomping the feet as when you do when using a floor mat, in a way of "shaking" the dust before entering the room/office.

Sometimes this habit (the stomping feet) may be done subconsciously even when the place doesn't have a floor mat. I've seen it done in circumstances where there is no floor mat.

And yes, it has this other characteristic that it draws attention as to avoid taking someone by surprise, or "announcing" your entrance or presence.

If this is more pronounced or customary in certain cultures I do not know, but it surely does read as something usual in *your* company.